# Pass in shell commands to bash function and execute them

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I need to pass in multiple shell commands to a bash function and execute them sequentially.

I have did something like this:

```
wloop () 
{( 
for i in ~/someFolder/*;
do
    pushd $i
    echo "$($@)";
    popd
done 
)}
```

And tried invoking the function like: `wloop 'cmd1'` and this works but on trying to provide multiple cmds like `wloop 'cmd1; cmd2'` didn't worked

Comment: `I need to pass in multiple shell commands to a bash function and execute them sequentially.` Then why do you `*.txt` do anything with txt files? Are they relevant?

Comment: @KamilCuk they are not much relevant, it could be also something like moving to a certain directories and executing the passed in commands.

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you want is an awful way to explain what you do want. If you want to evaluate `"$@"` as many times as there are matches on the wildcard, try `wloop () { for i in *.txt; do "$@"; done; }` but perhaps you are simply looking for `bash -c "$@"` ... or perhaps `for i in *.txt; do bash "$i"; done`

Comment: @PorottayumBeefum : What is the purpose of the variable `i`? It gets assigned, but is never used. For debugging, I suggest that you turn on `set -x`.

Comment: @user1934428 as i mentioned it before, it was just a prototype for my issue, i have edited the question

Comment: You don't need the `{...}` around the body of the function. A function just requires *a* compound command as its body. `(...)` is a compound command, so `wloop () ( ... )` or even `wloop () for i in ~/someFolder/*; do ...; done` is sufficient.

Comment: @PorottayumBeefum : Thank you. This is clearer now. So you want to execute the **same** command for every directory you do a `pushd` to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to execute in sequence command line arguments supplied to the shell?

I'd do it this way:

```
echo loop on $# arguments, executing each of them in sequence
while [ "$1" != "" ] ; do
        eval "$1"
        shift
done
```

The script above, when called with that line:

```
bash essai.sh 'var=1' 'echo hello' 'echo world' 'echo var=$var'
```

yields the following output:

```
loop on 4 arguments, executing each of them in sequence
hello
world
var=1
```

The same thing can be done with a function:

```
function wloop() {
    while [ "$1" != "" ] ; do
        eval $1
        shift
    done
    }

wloop 'var=1' 'echo hello' 'echo world' 'echo $var'
```

Additional remark: if we're using **shift**, your command line arguments can be executed only once (as after all the **shift**s the list of arguments will be 'exhausted'. So, if you want to run this sequence of commands several times (like your loop on *.txt suggests in your example), you should copy the command line arguments into an array instead of using shift:

```
function wloop() {
    args=("$@")
    for file in *.txt ; do 
        for i in $(seq 1 $#) ; do
            eval "${args[$i]}"
        done
    done
}
```

As the comment Gordon Davisson below points out, the "eval" command is prone to generate bugs.. it takes the string you supply to it and execute it as a command without discrimination. So, be careful with what you ask of it...

Comment: Warning: `eval` creates opportunities for confusion about when and how things get parsed, and as a result has a reputation as a bug magnet. In this case, there's an additional opportunity for trouble because you didn't double-quote `$1`, which can make things even weirder (try `wloop 'echo "2 * 2 = 4"'` to see what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

I would define a *second* function, and pass its name to `wloop`.

```
do_this () {
    cmd1
    cmd2
}

do_that () {
    cmd3
}

wloop () {
    for i in ~/someFolder/*; do
        pushd "$i"
        "$1"
        popd
    done
}

wloop do_this
wloop do_that
```